# Vaadin : set value to TextField "from server" doesn't trigger CustomField::generateModelValue

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have implemented CustomField which contains two simple textField.

```
public class MyCustomField extends CustomField<MyCustomPojo> {

    private TextField freeTextField;
    private TextField searchTextField;
    private Binder<MyCustomPojo> binder;
    private MyCustomPojo myCustomPojo;

    public MyCustomField(){

        this.binder = new Binder<>(MyCustomPojo.class);
        this.myCustomPojo = new MyCustomPojo();

        freeTextField = new TextField();
        searchTextField = new TextField();
        searchTextField.addFocusListener(event -> showSearchPopup());
}

    public void handleSearchResult(String searchResult){
        searchTextField.setValue(searchResult);
        this.updateValue();
    }


    @Override
    protected MyCustomPojo generateModelValue() {
        binder.writeBeanIfValid(this.customPojo);
        return this.customPojo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setPresentationValue(MyCustomPojo customPojo) {
        if(oriasModel != null) {
            this.customPojo= customPojo;
            binder.readBean(this.customPojo);
        }
    }

}
```

The first textField can be freely filled with any user input.
The second textField is a little bit special because when the user focus on it a search dialog is open and the user have to search for a data and then the textfield value is set with Textfield::setValue operation.

My issue is that the operation "generateModelValue" is never call when I set the textfield value from search result. But when I first search for fill "searchTextField" and then input manually the
"freeTextField", then  "generateModelValue" is called, and the resulting bean is populated.

Comment: If I understand this question correctly, the behavior is as intended. You have not added value change listener to your text field. You should probably add one and do explicit call to some method, which is not necessarily generateModelValue. Or even forget that and do proper things when setValue of the field itself is called. You probably are trying to populate your custom component, and want to trigger Binder validations.

Comment: The is that my custom component is used into a form with a binder. And when the value of subs fields is change by "handleSearchResult" then the form doesn't call getValue ou generateModelValue. It's seems that the form doesn't know that the value has changed. If the custom component has other fields, and if thoses fields are manually input, then the form does know that a change has been made.